# Finding duplicate value

Tags: mysql

I Have a table called EMPLOYEE

---

> | employee_id | name | supervisor_id |
>
> | 123 |         Ace Ven | NULL            |
>
> | 124                  |       Ben Agent | 123             |
>
> | 125                  |       Sam Marks | 123             |
>
> | 126                  |      Bob Teabag | 125             |
>
> | 127                  |   Matthew Smith | 125             |
>
> | 128                  |    Toby McQuire | 123             |

---

I am trying to find the supervisors and list the amount of employees they have. as you can see the supervisor_id is the same as employee_id. Should come out like this

---

> name | total_employees |
>
> Ace Ven | 3 |
>
> Sam Marks | 2 |

---

I tried

SELECT supervisor_id, name, count(supervisor_id) AS total_employees FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY name HAVING (total_employees > 0);

which didn't work at all (sorry about the format, can't seem to get it to work).

Comment: @Strawberry - Only "simple join"  will not reproduces result, what OP expects.

Comment: @otoshavadze I beg to differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subquery counts how many records/employees are for each supervisor_id, then this result simply joined table again for retrieving their names:

```
select your_table.name, t.total_employees from your_table
inner join 
(select supervisor_id, count(*) as total_employees  from your_table where supervisor_id is not null group by supervisor_id) t 
on your_table.employee_id = t.supervisor_id
```

Comment: That's a lot of query

Answer (score 0):

A simple join will suffice...

```
Select x.name
     , count(*) total
  from employee x 
  join employee y 
    on y.supervisor_id = x.employee_id 
 group 
    by x.employee_id;
```

Comment: @OtoShavadze Nope. This is fine because there is a functional dependency - although technically, name should be specified as unique.